# Como enviar váriaveis PHP usando Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Eu estou a fazer o carregamento da pagina através  do ajax mas como tenho que enviar parâmetros pelo url nao sei como os enviar com ajax  .

Eu tentei assim

```
<?php 
$album=$_GET['album'];
$id=$_GET['ntf'];
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "pegafotos.php?album=<?php echo $album ?>&nft=<?php echo $id  ?>",
    success: function(resp) {
        $("#result").html(resp);
    }
});
});
```

Div onde aparece o resultado

```
<div id="result"> Carregando <img src="css/images/gif.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading..." /></div>
```

Comment: Para além de faltar `;` a seguir a ambos os `echo` não vejo erros. Deve ser `<?php echo $album; ?>`. Fico com duvidas: Esse código está na mesma página? Pode explicar melhor qual é o papel do AJAX? como faz o AJAx correr? Se o AJAX corre quando a página carrega seria melhor ter só PHP sem AJAX...

Comment: Obrigado por reparar que faltava o ´;´ . Sim o código esta na mesma pagina ,o que o ajax esta ai a fazer e quando a pagina ´pegafotos.php´ tiver carregada a apaga o que esta na div e exibe os resultados que foram carregados da ´pegafotos.php´,so que tenho que passar parâmetros e nao os consigo enviar

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro. uma consideração. de que isso:

```
<?php
$album=$_GET['album'];
$id=$_GET['ntf'];
?>
```

Deveria ser, no mínimo, isso:

```
$album = ( isset( $_GET['album'] ) ? $_GET['album'] : 0 );
$id    = ( isset( $_GET['ntf'] )   ? $_GET['ntf']   : 0 );
```

Agora, quanto ao seu problema, AJAX é uma técnica para efetuar requisições assíncronas a um recurso localizado a partir de um determinado URI.

Pelo que dá pra entender do seu exemplo, o que você espera que aconteceria se a página requisitada fosse a mesma página que está requisitando? Assim:

```
<html>

    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js'></script>

    <?php

    $album = ( isset( $_GET['album'] ) ? $_GET['album'] : 0 );
    $id    = ( isset( $_GET['ntf'] )   ? $_GET['ntf']   : 0 );

    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( function() {

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "test.php",

            data: { album: <?php echo $album; ?>, id: <?php echo $id; ?> },

        }).done( function( data ) {

            $( "#result" ).html( data );

        });
    });

    </script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="result"> Carregando <img src="css/images/gif.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading..." /></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Seja por crédito extra ou por pura curiosidade você vai dezenas de requisições na aba Network/Rede do seu browser ou extensão à parte, caso não tenha nada nativo (Firebug).

O que você deveria fazer é separar o PHP num arquivo/URI e o JS que vai consumir em outro. Por exemplo:

**index.php**

```
$album = ( isset( $_GET['album'] ) ? $_GET['album'] : 0 );
$id    = ( isset( $_GET['ntf'] )   ? $_GET['ntf']   : 0 );

echo json_encode( array( 'album' => $album, 'id' => $id ) );
```

**index.html**

```
<html>

    <head>

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-compat-git.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    $( function() {

        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "index.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { album: 10, ntf: 20 },

        }).done( function( data ) {

            $( "#result" ).html( 'Album: ' + data.album + '. ID: ' + data.id );

        });
    });

    </script>


    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="result"> Carregando <img src="css/images/gif.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading..." /></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Assim, quando a Requisição for feita com sucesso o conteúdo da DIV será atualziado para, nesse exemplo, *Album: 10 ID: 20*

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta podia so me tirar um duvida ?Porque que no mínimo assim 
`$album = ( isset( $_GET['album'] ) ? $_GET['album'] : 0 );
$id    = ( isset( $_GET['ntf'] )   ? $_GET['ntf']   : 0 );`

Comment: É o mínimo de segurança ao se usar um valor vindo do usuário o qual pode não vir. Se você fizesse a requisição sem passar esses valores e por acaso seus alertas de erro estivessem baixos demais ou desabilitados, o JSON resultante, o qual a jQuery trabalharia, seria inválido.